# TableLayoutPanel размер последней колонки не равен размеру остальных

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `Panel`, в который помещена `TableLayoutPanel` c `Dock=Fill`.

Динамически наполняю `TableLayoutPanel` `Panel`'ами c кнопками: каждая кнопка `Dock=Fill` и помещена на `Panel` c `Dock=Fill`.

Предварительно размечаю `TableLayoutPanel`, указывая `RowCount` и `ColumnCount` в зависимости от количества кнопок. Также указываю `RowStyle` и `ColumnStyle` в `Percent`'ах, всегда константное число исходя из того, что сумма должна быть 100% (4% ширины и 50% высоты для каждой кнопки)

Но на деле ширина последней колонки выходит совсем не константная и не равна предыдущим колонкам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int totalCount = currentModels.Count();
                TableLayoutPanel tlp = (TableLayoutPanel)fp.Controls.Find("tlpInnerContainer", true)[0];
                    tlp.RowStyles.Clear();
                    tlp.ColumnStyles.Clear();
                    if (totalCount <= rowThreatsMaxCount)
                    {
                        tlp.ColumnCount = totalCount;
                        tlp.RowCount = 1;


                        for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
                        {
                            tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle { Width = 100 / (float)totalCount, SizeType = SizeType.Percent });
                        }
                        tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle { Height = 100 , SizeType = SizeType.Percent });
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        tlp.ColumnCount = rowThreatsMaxCount;
                        tlp.RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(totalCount / (double)rowThreatsMaxCount));
                        for (int i = 0; i < tlp.ColumnCount; i++)
                        {
                            tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle { Width = 100 / (float)rowThreatsMaxCount, SizeType = SizeType.Percent });
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < tlp.RowCount; i++)
                        {
                            tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle { Height = 100 / (float)tlp.RowCount, SizeType = SizeType.Percent });
                        }
                    }
```

Подскажите, в какую сторону искать решение данного бага ?

Answer (score 0):

Выставляйте принудительно ширину всех колонок в 100%

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Color oddColor = Color.Red;
    Color evenColor = Color.Yellow;
    int panelIndex = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelIndex++;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = panelIndex;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel.BackColor = panelIndex % 2 == 0 ? evenColor : oddColor;

        tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(panel, panelIndex - 1);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);

        for(int i=0; i< tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Count; i++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[i].Width = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]